# Column aggregate with table join on laravel 10

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, laravel-10

can anyone help me to find out how to get output like below

| name_transaction | NIM | Nama | SUM(`transactiondetails`.`amount`) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Data 1 | Data 1 | Data 1 |
| Data 2 | Data 2 | Data 2 | Data 2 |

I have 4 table,

[image]

I was try to group it like, but still hard for me to figure it out

Thank's for your help

I was try to group it like this

```
SELECT   SUM( `transactiondetails`.`amount` ) ,
         `transactions`.`id`,
         `transactions`.`type_transaction`,
         `transactions`.`depositor`,
         `typetransactions`.`name_transaction`,
         `mahasiswa`.`nim`,
         `mahasiswa`.`nama`,
         `transactions`.`deleted_at`
FROM     `transactions` 
LEFT JOIN `transactiondetails`  ON `transactions`.`id` = `transactiondetails`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `typetransactions`  ON `typetransactions`.`id` = `transactions`.`type_transaction` 
LEFT JOIN `mahasiswa`  ON `transactions`.`depositor` = `mahasiswa`.`id` 
WHERE    ( `transactions`.`deleted_at` is NULL )
GROUP BY `transactions`.`id`,
`mahasiswa`.`id`
```

and i got all the data, but not with sum of amount from transactiondetails. it's show null

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer, but not sure

```
SELECT   `transactions`.`id`,
         `typetransactions`.`name_transaction`,
         `mahasiswa`.`nama`,
         SUM( `transactiondetails`.`amount` )
FROM     `transactions`
LEFT JOIN `transactiondetails`  ON `transactions`.`id` = `transactiondetails`.`transaction`
LEFT JOIN `typetransactions`  ON `typetransactions`.`id` = `transactions`.`type_transaction`
LEFT JOIN `mahasiswa`  ON `mahasiswa`.`id` = `transactions`.`depositor`
WHERE    ( `transactions`.`deleted_at` is NULL ) AND ( `transactiondetails`.`deleted_at` is NULL  )
GROUP BY `transactions`.`id`
```